# Is there a javascript library for generating litecoin address from a string?

Tags: address, litecoin, address-generation, brain-wallet

Is there a bitcoinjs equivalent for litecoin? I want to be able to generate a litecoin address using a long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore-lib.
You can generate a Litecoin address with a long string by using above library.